# How to make the global-mark-ring a frame-local variable in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, navigation

I'm using nameframe-perspective mode and I'd like to navigate back and forth in Emacs such as the mark buffer is stored per-frame.
I tried to execute (make-variable-frame-local 'global-mark-ring) but it doesn't help: still the mark ring is shared between frames.
Is there a way to make it frame-local?
Appreciate your inputs!

Comment: The `frame-bufs` library by Alp Aker stores the `frame-bufs-buffer-list` in the `frame-parameters`, giving users the ability to associate buffers with a particular frame.  You could use a similar concept to store frame-local stuff.  In terms of the `global-mark-ring` and/or `perspective`, I haven't the slightest idea about using them -- sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm looking for a way to alter a variable

Comment: I'm looking for a way to alter `global-mark-ring` variable for a frame, so all the packages which use this variable, will see a frame-bound version of the variable. Thanks for a hint regarding frame-bufs.